What is equivalent to walletcreatefundedpsbt but with an arbitrary funding wallet?
I'm interested in creating a swap application using HTLCs. The user connects their wallet to the frontend, places an order, and the backend matches the order with a maker and creates the HTLC transaction. The user's UTXOs are used as inputs to fund the transaction, and the single non-change output is the one with the HTLC as the unlocking script. The flow would look similar to the one depicted here:

However, I don't want the backend to have to do the coin selection and figure out which UTXOs are optimal to fund the transaction. From my understanding, normally the walletcreatefundedpsbt RPC method would do that for you, but in this case the wallet in question is the user's wallet. Is there an equivalent way I can do coin selection for someone else's wallet?

No, coin selection does not have a public API nor any RPCs to operate on arbitrary UTXO pools. The only way to use Bitcoin Core's coin selection algorithms is to create a wallet that has the relevant scripts imported so that it detects the UTXOs and can do coin selection on them.

How would one typically accomplish this then? I notice that mempool.space's GET Address UTXO endpoint does something similar:

Get the list of unspent transaction outputs associated with the address/scripthash. Available fields: txid, vout, value, and status (with the status of the funding tx).

However this would only work for a single address in the derivation sequence.
